# Need to automatically sign out a Instant Messenger user when browser window is closed

Tags: javascript, chat, logout, onbeforeunload

I have a Web-based Chat application, that refreshes periodically say every 30 secs, polling for new messages. If the user does not explicitly sign out using a "Sign Out"  button, but accidentally closes the browser window, it should automatically sign him/her out of the Chat Application.

Tried the following code - on the onbeforeunload event, but the problem with this is, it fires for every refresh of the window, which is not want I want.

```
function CloseSession() {
        location.href = 'IMSignOut.aspx';
}
window.onbeforeunload = CloseSession;
```

Any Ideas on how to prevent the unload event from firing with every refresh? or have the CloseSession function called only on window closing?

Comment: What about doing the reverse?  If the browser window is open, it's sending a request for additional messages, during which, you could reset the flag to automatically log them out.  A script on the server side -- running every 30 seconds -- would log the user out if they haven't requested additional messages in the past 30 seconds.

Comment: I see your point. But the logged in user needn't  be sending or receiving messages all the time.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear.  I didn't mean they were sending actual messages.  I meant the browser was sending "keep-alives" by polling for new messages.  I'm saying the default task on your server would be to log users out, with the browser being open preventing that from happening.